# How to correctly manage a Thread's lifecycle from a Service?

Tags: android, android-service

I've noticed something while I was reading the `Service` `API` Guide (more specifically [this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService)). In the following code snippet, a new `HandlerThread` is created and started every time the `Service` is created:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
        Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
  }
```

But this thread is never stopped after that. So, my question is: why there is not any explicit call to a stop method? I'm asking this because I'm wondering what is going to happen to any thread created by a `Service` if the `Service` itself gets killed by the system. How can I make sure that everything will be cleaned up?

Comment: The way this works is that you have a thread, the threads handler (messege queue) and then the threads looper who dispatches these messages. When you have no messages the thread s not actually running but is in a waiting state ready to accept. If you want to clean up your threads you would have to do as with any thread in the onDestroy() function.

Comment: But what if the service gets killed and onDestroy() never gets called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if a Service is killed and taken out of memory, then the thread will be killed with it. Any messages in the queue will be removed and aborted.  This is probably why they don't show the thread being quit in the `onDestroy` method.

However, if you want to end the thread, [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html#quit()) has the methods `quit()` and `quitSafely()` (API >= 18).  You would put these in the `onDestroy()` method of your service.  The difference between the two is `quit()` will kill the thread as soon as possible while `quitSafely()` will kill the thread as soon as all messages are complete.  However, like stated earlier, the thread will probably die before that happens anyway.

EDIT:

To clarify, the thread will be killed when the system kills the app process.  For services that have a permanent worker thread like the example showed, there isn't much of a need for cleanup because everything is going to get cleaned up anyway.

More temporary services though may require you to shut down the threads manually because you're killing the service yourself.  When this happens, the app process is still going to be active which means the threads you created will still be active so these will have to be shut down as stated in the original answer.  `IntentService` though is usually a better option for this since it's already doing all the thread handling for you.

Comment: Are you sure that the threads will be killed with the Service? Because I thought that any threads created by a service would be independent from the service itself, in a sense that their existence would be related not to this service, but to an application process. Which would mean that when the service (not the process) is killed by the system, any threads created by it would remain untouched, since the process would still be alive.

Comment: Ok, I was reading some stuff about processes and services and I discovered that when the system 'kills a service' it is in fact killing the process hosting the service. So, correct me if I'm wrong, but there is no such thing as killing an individual app component, which means that apparently you are right: if a service gets killed by the system, all threads  started by it will be killed as well (as long as they are in the same process).

Comment: Well, ok.  To clarify, if the system itself kills the service, it is most likely killing the process. It will try to close Activities first since hidden Activities are far less valuable, but by the time it gets to a Service it is pretty much going to close it.  If the service is to always run when the app is active, then this is what will happen.

Comment: However, your app can have multiple services running.  Most of which can be temporary.  If they are, then it's possible for *you* to destroy the Service in which case, yes.  If you don't shut down the threads, they will keep running until the system destroys the process.  IntentService is basically doing exactly all this behind the scenes.